# Book where gladiators representing geographic areas fight using primitive weapons

Tags: story-identification

Does anyone know the title of a science fiction book with a plot of gladiator type champions from each major geographic area of the world such as North America, Australia, etc. that are forced to fight for their area--some use trench knives, some swords, some spears, etc. It came out prior to 1970.

Comment: First line and a half of that question describes Hunger Games perfectly... >_>

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a story by Mack Reynolds. It is part of his Joe Mauser series. It was published in a few different versions. The one I read was called "Sweet Dreams, Sweet Princes", published in 1986. It was apprently published as "Time Gladiator" in the late 60's.
Each area would have an olympics style competition (blood sport) to select their champions, who would then represent them in international disputes. Trial by combat, survivors win the dispute.